# Very basic Spring websocket returns 404

Tags: java, websocket

I am learning to use Spring WebSockets, but I cannot get a very basic example to work, I receive a 404 error.
I used http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/websocket.html as a reference.

The WebSocketConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocket
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketConfigurer {
    private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(WebSocketConfig.class);

    @Override
    public void registerWebSocketHandlers(WebSocketHandlerRegistry registry) {
        logger.debug("Registering websocket handler");
        registry.addHandler(gameWebSocketHandler(), "/StreamGame/ws/play");
    }

    @Bean
    public WebSocketHandler gameWebSocketHandler() {
        return new GameWebSocketHandler();
    }
}
```

The WebSocketHandler:

```
public class GameWebSocketHandler extends TextWebSocketHandler {
    final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(GameWebSocketHandler.class);

    public GameWebSocketHandler() {
        logger.debug("Constructor handler");
    }

    @Override
    public void handleTransportError(WebSocketSession session, Throwable exception) throws Exception {
        super.handleTransportError(session, exception);
        logger.error("Transport error: " + exception.getMessage());
    }

    @Override
    public void handleTextMessage(WebSocketSession session, TextMessage message) throws Exception {
        logger.info("Handle message received: " + message.getPayload());
        //session.sendMessage(new TextMessage("Here is your answer"));
    }

    @Override
    public void afterConnectionEstablished(WebSocketSession session) throws Exception {
        super.afterConnectionEstablished(session);
        logger.info("Connection established!");
    }
}
```

Unless I am mistaking, even with this I should be able to send a message through a websocket from the client to the server as following:

```
sock = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080/StreamGame/ws/play');
```

I receive the following error on connect:

> Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404WrappedWebSocket @ VM84:35(anonymous function) @ (index):11j @ jquery-3.1.1.min.js:2k @ jquery-3.1.1.min.js:2
>   (index):26 Error undefined

Web.xml contains the following:

```
   <!-- Processes application requests -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/application-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
       <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
       </listener-class>
    </listener> 
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>SpringMVCDispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/application-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <!-- Mapping websocket to spring dispatcher servlet -->
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>SpringMVCDispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/ws/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

My Spring application context contains:

When connecting the websocket I see the following in the server logs:

```
>     2016-11-13 TRACE - 39804 - org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet -
> http-nio-8080-exec-2 - Bound request context to thread:
> org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@df5f117
>     2016-11-13 DEBUG - 39804 - org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet -
> http-nio-8080-exec-2 - DispatcherServlet with name
> 'SpringMVCDispatcherServlet' processing GET request for
> [/StreamGame/ws/play]
>     2016-11-13 TRACE - 39804 - org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet -
> http-nio-8080-exec-2 - Testing handler map
> [org.springframework.web.socket.server.support.WebSocketHandlerMapping@4e92ebf3]
> in DispatcherServlet with name 'SpringMVCDispatcherServlet'
>     2016-11-13 TRACE - 39804 - org.springframework.web.socket.server.support.WebSocketHandlerMapping
> - http-nio-8080-exec-2 - No handler mapping found for [/play]
>     2016-11-13 WARN  - 39804 - org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - http-nio-8080-exec-2 -
> No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/StreamGame/ws/play] in
> DispatcherServlet with name 'SpringMVCDispatcherServlet'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The addHandler function needs to be mapped to '/play', so excluding the root-context (StreamGame) and the dispatcher mapping (/ws). Changing the addHandler solved the issue:

```
registry.addHandler(gameWebSocketHandler(), "/play");
```

The websocket connected when opening it as following:

```
sock = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080/StreamGame/ws/play');
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems your websocket url is incorrect. You registered **/play** as handler but call **/StreamGame/play**

Also keep in mind that the ws connection is created asynchronously, so you have to wait for the connection handshake to finish before sending messages, like so:

```
var ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080/play");
ws.onopen = function() {
    ws.send('AHOIHOI');
}
ws.onerror = function(error) {
    // handle connection error
}
```

Comment: Hi,

Thank you for your advice. I have tried to change the websocket configuration to /StreamGame/play, but same result:
registry.addHandler(gameWebSocketHandler(), "/StreamGame/play");

Comment: Okay, if your classes aren't instantiated then it cannot work. Did you use Spring-Boot to setup the application? If not you might forgot to set the component scan classpath correctly.

Comment: Hi Quagaar,

I added my application-context.xml and web.xml to my original post. Do I need to define anything more in my web.xml?

Comment: If you mix xml and Java config, then you have to add the following to your application context xml: <context:annotation-config/>

Comment: Thanks Quagaar,

I added the annotation-config tag and also added a mapping of the websocket request to SpringDispatcherServlet. I can now see the logging I added in the handler constructor. So they are now instantiated, but the websocket connection still returns a 404 :(. I do see the following in the log though:
Mapped URL path [/StreamGame/play] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.socket.server.support.WebSocketHttpRequestHandler]

Comment: Could you add the changes you made to your question?

Comment: Hi Quagaar,

I updated the question. I am not 100% sure if I need to add the root-context in the addhandler statement, so I also tried it without but no difference. Now that I have more logging I can see that there is something wrong with the mapping?

Comment: Found it, the addhandler needed to be mapped to "/play'. When doing so, the connection is established. Thanks for pointing to me on my other mistakes to be able to get to this conclusion.